# Heroku action before/after deploy

Tags: heroku, deployment, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy Laravel app to Heroku. Everything is fine but I don't know how to make custom actions before/after deployment (git push).

I need to copy files and run `artisan migrate` command after the deployment. How can I do that?

I used OpenShift before and I've been used action hooks to do this tasks, but I can't find any equivalent option...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huroku offers ["release phase"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase) (beta) for running script after a release is created.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Heroku's Dev Centre](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-laravel)

On setting up laravel with Heroku

Comment: @nrofis as in auto deploy, or dynos?

Comment: Auto deploy, after deploy run script (copy files and migrate for example)

Comment: In order to run scripts you ought to configure the app dyno

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Have you already activated auto deploy in heroku?.. if not, click the deploy tab and turn auto deploy on.. afterwards check out your addons tab.. you should see the option to configure dynos.. .. the dyno is basically a command you would like to be executed after deploy... in node.. say you want to run `npm start` after deploy.. if your dyno is set to `npm start` , it will run right after deploy.. I don't do laravel or php.. but the configuration should be similar

Comment: If you're pushing to heroku straight, it will auto deploy if it is github, then you have to activate auto deploy.... what method of deploy are you using?

Comment: Pushing my local repository (on my machine) with git to Heroku

Comment: Oh okay. . The auto deploy already works  after you run `git push heroku master`... so configure your dyno to run the script

Comment: I have one dyno `web vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/` (in Procfile). How can I configure it?

Comment: I am using free plan, I can have one free dyno (my `web ...`). Can I add more dynos?

Comment: You can try the other plan that costs $7.00.. according to heroku, you will only pay for how much you use... so you won't necessarily pay $7.00 a month.. you can pay lower or nothing at all.. try it out.. and lmk if it works for you

Comment: The dynos can be set up in the CLI.. it's well detailed in one of the links I sent you... it should work with your free plan. ....

Comment: Sorry then... you may want to upgrade to hobby or standard